# How to count number of same array elements in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I count same elements in array, for example if I have an array of `5` integers like this `arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` output should be : `0` since there's no repeated elements, but if I have `arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5};` output should be : `2` since `1` is repeated `2` times and so on. I've tried to solve this with the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++){
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
            cnt++;
        }

     }

    }
     cout << cnt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is `2`, but the current output for this code is `1`.

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1};
```

expected output is `4`, but the current output for this is `6`.

What's wrong with this code?
 Sometimes it outputs the expected, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: the code is running fine, your logic is wrong

Comment: you are counting the number of times a number is duplicated rather then the number of instances of duplicated numbers. It's not the same thing.

Comment: This is a good example where it can be helpful to "go through" the code on paper. Write down the array, go through the loops and write down whenever `cnt` increases. It should show you why your last example ends up with `6` instead of `4`.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri I know that my logic is wrong, and that's why I posted this question.

Comment: i have written the answer for the correction currently, will edit it with right logic

Comment: you should avoid sayin `What's wrong with this code?`, as it is behaving as expected

Comment: i updated my answer with correct logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine, let me show how:

when `arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4};`

i = 0 => a[i] = 1 will be matched with j = 1 (a[j] = 1)

therefore count is 1

when `arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1};`

i = 0 => a[i] = 1 will be matched with j = 1, 3, 4 => count = 3

i = 1 will be matched with j = 3, 4 => count = 5

i = 3 will be matched with j = 4 => count = 6

This is the output you are getting, as per the code you wrote; which is totally correct. The error lies in your logic.

This is the correct logic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){
    int arr[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1};
    int cnt = 0;

    std::map<int, int> mp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     mp[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for(auto it=mp.begin(); it!=mp.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->second==1)
            continue;
        else
            cnt +=it->second;
    }
     std::cout << cnt << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You store all the values in a map with their frequencies and increase the count whenever the frequency is greater than 1.

Comment: Could you explain what map does?

Comment: map is like an associative array, in array the indices can only be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4..... but in map the index can be anything - char, string, float, struct, class, template etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some functions of the standard template library (STL).
`std::sort()` to sort the array, which helps to count repetitions using `std::unique()`, because it needs a sorted container.

At first you sort your array, and then you count repetitions with a comparer while `std::unique()` removes repetitions from the array. The code can store the count of unique elements which are repeated, and count the removed elements. So in the end, you can sum the count of removed elements with the count of unique elements that had repetitions.

My example is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int32_t SIZE = 7;
    int32_t ArrInput[SIZE]{1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 4};

    std::sort(ArrInput, ArrInput+SIZE);

    int32_t CountRemovedRepetitions = 0;
    std::map<int32_t, int32_t> MapAllUniqueRepetition;

    std::unique(ArrInput, ArrInput+SIZE,
        [&MapAllUniqueRepetition, &CountRemovedRepetitions](const int32_t v1, const int32_t v2) {
            if (v1 == v2) {
                MapAllUniqueRepetition[v1]++;
                CountRemovedRepetitions++;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    int32_t CountTotalRepetitions = MapAllUniqueRepetition.size() + CountRemovedRepetitions;
    std::cout << "Count removed repetitions:" << CountRemovedRepetitions << " and count total repetiotions: " << CountTotalRepetitions << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result of program is:

```
Count removed repetitions:3 and count total repetiotions: 5
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Also I have to tell that `ArrInput` will remove duplicated elements and will be sorted. So if you need just to count you should copy ArrInput in temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are map unique keys to non-unique values. Each time we find a value in the array, you simply increment the number of times you saw it (the value).

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  vector<int>   a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1};

  // Associative array that associates
  // keys (values from the array) and values,
  // (the number of times we find a given key)
  map<int, int> m;
  int           n = a.size();

  // Total number of duplicates, we start
  // at zero, and we will add all the values
  // that exceed 1 in our map.
  int           sum = 0;

  // Iterates over map
  map<string, int>::iterator it;

  // Loop through array / vector
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    // Add 1 to the value associated
    // with the key a[i]
    m[ a[i] ] += 1;

  }

  // Loop through the map
  for (auto it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it) {

    // If a given value was found
    // more than once, add the number of
    // times we found it to the running sum
    if (it->second > 1) {
      sum += it->second;
    }

  }

  // Overall sum of duplicates found
  cout << sum << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```